# bash script - how to do something based on the result of a psql query

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Need help trying to parse these results from within a unix shell script.
I'm looking to grab the result of `1` and the logic would be:
if `1` exists then proceed with rest of the code else exit.

Here's the command line string that runs my query followed by the results in STDOUT.

```
/bin/psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U mas postgres -c "SELECT 1 as result from pg_database WHERE datname='mydbname'";
Password for user mas:
  result
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

What I need help is contructing the `if-then-else` logic with some string parser so I can get just `1` and compare against that. How to do that?

Comment: [man psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/app-psql.html) suggests `--tuples-only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[man psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/app-psql.html) suggests that you can use `--tuples-only` to just get the value, avoiding the need to parse.